# Ошибка Traceback (most recent call last): в requests.get

Tags: python, requests

Вот код

```
import requests as req
import pyperclip
api = req.get("https://api.thealtening.com/v2/generate?key=api-****-****-****&info=true").json()

print(f'NAME: {api["username"]}'
      f'\nValid: {api["valid"]}'
      f'\nTOKEN: {api["token"]} - copied to clipboard!')
```

а вот ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.thealtening.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/generate?key=api-j62u-u2ak-wtub&info=true (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\romaz\Desktop\teests\thealtapi.py", line 3, in <module>
    api = req.get("https://api.thealtening.com/v2/generate?key=api-j62u-u2ak-wtub&info=true").json()
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.thealtening.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/generate?key=api-j62u-u2ak-wtub&info=true (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

по этому запросу thealtening генерирует акк

Comment: Добавьте в параметры get запроса `verify=False`. А лучше достаньте CA сертификат сервера и указывайте его при запросах, так безопаснее.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов не работает

Comment: @МихаилМуругов к тому же безапасность тут не нужна

Comment: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '6ijf1-r0ya0@alt.com': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://6ijf1-r0ya0@alt.com? с использованием verify=False

Comment: вот как выглядит json которую генерирует thealtening {"token":"ye1td-a0zi0@alt.com","password":"anything","username":"dani28**","limit":false,"skin":"0430d2ab379c4cf485765590eaddcc2a","info":{},"valid":true,"expires":"2021-09-29T06:04:05.340291+00:00"}